# unstacking a list of lists into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the below dataframe:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'a':['x, y', 'x, t, x, r', 'y, t'],
          'b':[1, 0, 1]})

            a  b
0        x, y  1
1  x, t, x, r  0
2        y, t  1
```

I would like to get to

```
  letter  num
0      x    1
1      y    1
2      x    0
3      t    0
4      x    0
5      r    0
6      y    1
7      t    1
```

I have solved the issue the following way, but I feel like i'm making it more complicated than it needs to be.

```
x.a = x.a.str.split(",")

empty = []
for b, a in zip(x.b, x.a):
    empty.append([b] * len(a))

t = [item for sublist in empty for item in sublist]
y = [item for sublist in x.a for item in sublist]

pd.DataFrame({'letter':t, 'num':y})

   letter num
0       1   x
1       1   y
2       0   x
3       0   t
4       0   x
5       0   r
6       1   y
7       1   t
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `list`s first by regex - `,\s+` for comma with one or more spaces, and then [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with flatenning by [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) and last `DataFrame` constructor:

```
a = x.a.str.split(",\s+")
b = np.repeat(x.b.values, a.str.len())
c = np.concatenate(a.values)

df = pd.DataFrame({'letter':c, 'num':b})
print (df)
  letter  num
0      x    1
1      y    1
2      x    0
3      t    0
4      x    0
5      r    0
6      y    1
7      t    1
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's expand each row by one plus the number of commas in column `'a'`.  Then overwrite column `'a'` with new values.

```
x.loc[
    x.index.repeat(x.a.str.count(', ') + 1)
].assign(
    a=', '.join(x.a).split(', ')
).rename(columns=dict(a='letter', b='num'))

  letter  num
0      x    1
0      y    1
1      x    0
1      t    0
1      x    0
1      r    0
2      y    1
2      t    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just find a new way :-)

```
x.set_index('b').a.str.get_dummies(sep=',').replace(0,np.nan).stack().reset_index().drop(0,1)
Out[481]: 
   b level_1
0  1       y
1  1       x
2  0       r
3  0       t
4  0       x
5  0       x
6  1       t
7  1       y
```